# RickShaw Charting - Minimum required files to create charts

Tags: jquery, d3.js, rickshaw

i've downloaded the zip file of RickShaw from https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw

My question what are the files i need to include or reference to create rickshaw charts? just the .min.js files, or do i need the css files as well?

Thanks

Comment: Simply trying it would probably have been faster than posting the question here.

Comment: 'trying it' sometimes may get you what you are looking for now, but i wonder if there may be other functionality that would not be if the css files are not included.

Comment: Without having looked at it, I would assume that the CSS files are there for a reason.